# Updating sort order using Jquery sortable and gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

I have a gridview that I am populating with SQL data.  I am able to sort the records using jQuery soratble.  When I click on the btnUpdadateSortOrder button and run the my script, I receive no errors however the sort order doesn't update.  after I drag and drop to create a new order my array seems to keep the old order.  what should I be using to set my vid_id()????

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gvVideos" CssClass="gvVideosClass" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerId"
        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added.">
        <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="customerId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("customerId")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblcustomerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("customerId")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="160px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fid" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblvidID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fID")%>' />
                    <input type="hidden" name="vidId" value='<%# Eval("fId")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>



            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>


        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateSortOrder" runat="server" Text="Update Sort Order"
            OnClick="btnUpdateSortOrder_Click" />
```

here is my codebehind

```
  ' stores id_ in array
    Dim vid_id As String() = New String(gvVideos.Rows.Count - 1) {}
    For i As Integer = 0 To gvVideos.Rows.Count - 1
        vid_id(i) = CInt(DirectCast(gvVideos.Rows(i).Cells(1).FindControl("vidId"), Label).Text)
    Next

   ' This worked at one point but now doesn't.       
      'Dim id_language As String() = Request.Form.GetValues("fId")
    Dim sortNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim mySort As New vidController
    ' Loop over array, which contains id_ 
    For Each i As String In vid_id
        ' method which which fire update query order save into database
        mySort.updateVidSortOrder(i, sortNumber)
        sortNumber += 1
    Next
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

working code:

```
  Dim vid_id As String() = Request.Form.GetValues("vidId")
    Dim sortNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim mySort As New vidController
    ' Loop over array, which contains id 
    For Each i As String In vid_id
        ' method which which fire update query order save into database
        mySort.updateVidSortOrder(i, sortNumber)
        sortNumber += 1
    Next
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

Comment: not sure if you suggesting or asking :D, but no not using updatepanel.

Comment: updatepanel didn't work either :(

Comment: please show your javascript and `btnUpdateSortOrder_Click`event.

Comment: it's vb.net code behind

Comment: I updated the codehind.  Now sure why these values are not refreshing...  I wonder if there is an easier way like a datalist or something.  what am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribut to your grid view:  AllowSorting="True"

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  Still getting the same result in my array vid_id(i). Any other thoughts, my DOM show's correct order... but not code behind

Comment: http://codepedia.info/2015/03/reorder-gridview-asp-net-jquery-drag-drop-reorder-of-gridview-rows/#comment-284, this is the source where I am updating sort order. Request.Form.GetValues("vidId") this doesn't seem to work, thinking maybe because it has to be a boundfield?  been fighting with this for a couple days now :S

Comment: I found the fix 

 'Dim vid_id As String() = Request.Form.GetValues("vidId")  I updated my code above to refleck.  How do I convert this to an answer.